# DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Ajax error with SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on Visual Studio 2017 with C# ASP.NET MVC and I am totally new in Ajax,

and I tried using Ajax code with some modification related to my project,

my idea in the first view which is called AOIAdmin.cs, I will display all area of interest of projects, and behind each area, there is three button 1.View, 2. Edit, 3. Delete

First I loaded data of the area of interest from SQL Server database in AreaOfInterestController.cs

```
public ActionResult loaddata()
    {
        using (Entities dc = new Entities())
        {
            var temp = dc.AreaOFInterests.OrderBy(a => a.AOIName).ToList();
            var data = temp.Select(S => new { AOIName = S.AOIName, AOIId = S.AOIId });
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and showing area of interest in AOIAdmin.cs view and AOIAdmin.cs view  look like,

```
<table id="myTable" style="width:100%; border:solid;" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr style="border:solid;">
        <th> Name</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
@section Scripts{
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/AreaOfInterest/loaddata",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "AOIName", "autoWidth": true },
                {
//View button
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a style ="background :none;" class="btn btn-default btn-md glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" href="/AreaOfInterest/EachAreaAdmin/' + full.AOIId + '"></a>'; }
                },
                {
//Edit button
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/AreaOfInterest/Edit/' + full.AOIId + '">Edit</a>'; }
                },

                {
//Delete button
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/AreaOfInterest/Delete/' + row.AOIId + '"  onclick=DeleteData("' + row.AOIId + '"); >Delete</a>";

                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });


</script>
}
```

when admin pressing on View button in AOIAdmin view I wand display all project in the area of interest in the same row, so I tried load projects from SQL Server database in AreaOfInterestController.cs like this (I am sure the query is right)

```
public ActionResult loadEachArea(int? id)
    {
        using (Entities dc = new Entities())
        {

            var sp = (from m in dc.SeniorProjects
                      join s in dc.ProjectsAOIs on m.SPtId equals s.SPtId
                      where s.AOIId == id
                      select m);
            var temp = sp.OrderBy(a => a.SPtId).ToList();
            var data = sp.Select(S => new { SPName = S.SPName, SPId = S.SPtId });
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and using loaded projects in EachAreaAdmin.cs view

```
<table id="myTable" style="width:100%; border:solid;" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr style="border:solid;">
        <th> Name</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script 

src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/AreaOfInterest/loadEachArea,
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "SPName", "autoWidth": true },
                {

                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a style ="background :none;" class="btn btn-default btn-md glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" href="/AreaOfInterest/Project/' + full.SPtId + '"></a>'; }
                },
                {

                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/SeniorProjects/Edit/' + full.SPtId + '">Edit</a>'; }
                },

                {
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.SPtId + "'); >Delete</a>";
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });
```

but when pressing View button in AOIAdmin.cs view showing

> DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Ajax error.

how to send id with loadEachArea method or where is the problem?

Edit:

I uploaded [browser's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozaZF.png) and [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri6Sw.png), but I did not understand it,

I hope you understand me, Thank you

Comment: you should check your browser's console and Network tabs (in the developer tools) and look at the ajax request to see what actually went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If you didn't understand it, did you google it? That should be your first thought. A 500 Internal Server Error is a generic message which means your server crashed when trying to respond to the request. So probably it threw an exception somewhere. Therefore you should check your server's logs and event viewer to see if any exceptions were raised. That way you can start to find the real source of the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I was think the problem because of id of area of interest, but I will try more to solve this problem,